# How to do conditional formatting in one cell SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a problem with the conditional formatting of a cell in SSRS 2008 R2.

My problem is that I have two types of data in this cell, one is a string, and other is a numer (percentage).

[image: My Table]

My expression :

```
="Critical :"& Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA" And Fields!sla_string.Value = "dentro sla", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing)) / Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing)) 
& chr(10) & chr(13) & 
"Major :" & Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA" And Fields!sla_string.Value = "dentro sla", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing)) / Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing)) 
& chr(10) & chr(13) & 
"Minor :" & Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA" And Fields!sla_string.Value = "dentro sla", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing)) / Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing))
```

The idea is to have something like this:

Critical: 90%

Major: 35%

Minor: 53%

And I have a result like this:

[image]

I create a placeholder because I see a lot of guys in the forums saying it was the only way possible to do conditional formatting in a cell, but now I'm stuck in this part.

The question is: How can I put a string and a number in the same cell with diferent formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply formatting to the various numeric parts of the expression when you're constructing the cell details:

```
="Critical :"
  & Format(Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA" And Fields!sla_string.Value = "dentro sla", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing))
    / Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing)), "P0")
& vbcrlf & 
"Major :" & Format(Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA" And Fields!sla_string.Value = "dentro sla", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing))
    / Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing)), "P0")
& vbcrlf & 
"Minor :" & Format(Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA" And Fields!sla_string.Value = "dentro sla", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing))
    / Count(IIF(Fields!Prioridade.Value = "ALTA", Fields!TicketId.Value, Nothing)), "P0")
```

That way you don't need to set up six placeholders with different expression/formatting and keep it in one expression per cell.

`Format` just supplies a text value for a numeric based on a specified numeric format - here `P0` is just saying format as % with no decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

could you use round()?

e.g. -

`="Critical :"& ROUND(IIF(.....),2)`